# html table with javascript sp

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I am a beginner who recently started working with Javascript and I want to simplify my code. How can I simplify this? How would I apply a loop because it is too long to declare it by a single code if I want to change the `id`. Not manually changing in the html, but using a Javascript to change the value in html?

```
<table border="2" cellpadding="4">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell1"> one </td>
            <td id="cell2"> two </td>
            <td id="cell3"> three </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell4"> four </td>
            <td id="cell5"> five </td>
            <td id="cell6"> six </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

document.getElementById("cell1").innerHTML="1";                                     
document.getElementById("cell2").innerHTML="2";                                     
document.getElementById("cell3").innerHTML="3";                                     
document.getElementById("cell4").innerHTML="4";                                     
document.getElementById("cell5").innerHTML="5";                                     
document.getElementById("cell6").innerHTML="6";
```

Comment: can you please try out code given by me, or check on jsfiddle

Comment: one more suggestion please use id for table also .....rather than id for cells

Comment: I think this question belongs to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MickaëlB - what make you think like that ...its programming question there are lot of question like this on stackoverflow

Comment: @PranayRana This code is actually working. The problem looks like a code optimization to me. That's the all point of CR.

Comment: please do upvote/accept answer if it works for you...........

Answer (score 1):

try this code using `for loop`

```js
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0, j = 1; i <= items.length - 1; i++, j++) {
  items[i].innerHTML = j;
}
```

```html
<table border="2" cellpadding="4">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell1"> one </td>
      <td id="cell2"> two </td>
      <td id="cell3"> three </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell4"> four </td>
      <td id="cell5"> five </td>
      <td id="cell6"> six </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what if there ar more than one table .................you cannot do this kind of thing it will update whole html , better to have id for element ...means id for table

Comment: What if the html document have two table on it ...try out code by putting to table ...better you have good reason to down vote...let me know whey you are ready with jsfiddle code ...

Comment: i am still waiting for you jsfiddle wroking code .............mr. smart guy

Answer (score -1):

i hope that help you and you can start learn javascript on this site https://www.w3schools.com/js/ is very useful:

```
var d = document;
var trs = d.getElementsByTagName("tr");
console.log(trs);
var count = 1;
for(var i=0 ; i<trs.length ; i++){
    tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for(var j=0 ; j<tds.length ; j++){
        tds[j].innerHTML = count;
      count++;
    }
    console.log(trs[i]);
}
```

Comment: I didnt down vote your answer but its better you get table element by ID and than try your code ....because right now it will go and search all tr element on page , and what if there is two table on your page ...it will affect all

Comment: yeah of course, that just an exemple to have an idea about foor loop and how to get element using javascript and do some stuff to it ,

Comment: seems like some one putting minus point without any reason...its exaple but you can update code